# Dúvida Flutter: ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

Bom dia!

Alguém poderia me auxiliar em uma dúvida?

O que estou fazendo:

Fiz um search para o usuário pesquisar por uma Infração ou Anexos etc no app, e logo após a ação no teclado eu redireciono ele para outro pagina (FiltroInicioView) passando os dados como parâmetro.

```
onFieldSubmitted: (string) {
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => FiltroinicioView(filterNomeInfracao, filterNomeAnexo),
    ),
  );
},
```

Após, redirecionar o usuário para a pagina de View da infração e anexos pesquisada, Eu mostro a Lista das Infrações, e anexos,

```
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          itemCount: filterNomeInfracao.length +
              filterNomeAnexo.length 
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            print(filterNomeInfracao);
            print(filterNomeAnexo);

          },
```

Retorno do Print:

```
[Infracao{id: null, descricao:  , codigo: INFRAÇÕES, art_ctb: null, pontuacao_id: null, observacao: null, foto: null, procedimento_id: null, categoria_id: null, created: null, modified: null, deleted: null}, Infracao{id: 34, descricao: CONFIAR/ ENTREGAR  veículo a pessoa em estado FÍSICO/ PSÍQUICO SEM CONDIÇÕES  de dirigir com segurança, codigo: 517-7_0, art_ctb: 166, pontuacao_id: 5, observacao: Conforme Resolução CONTRAN 561/2015.

 [Anexo{id: 40, nome: GESTOS DE AGENTES, conteudo: movimentos convencionais de braço, adotados exclusivamente pelos agentes de autoridades de trânsito nas vias, para orientar, indicar o direi
```

Minha dúvida é como eu consigo saber agora dentro do **itemBuilder**: (BuildContext context, int index) {
qual lista é de **Infracoes** e qual Lista é de **anexos** porque eu preciso fazer um IF agora ou seja

```
if(for a lista ANEXOS){
faz alguma coisa
}


if( for a lista INFRACOES){
faz alguma coisa
}
```

**CONFORME CITADO NO COMENTARIO A FORMA FEITA:**

```
   body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                itemCount: filterNomeInfracao.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (index < filterNomeInfracao.length) {
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 20.0, 1.0),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              'INFRAÇÕES.',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 28.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                  return ListaInfracao(filterNomeInfracao[index]);
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                itemCount: filterNomeInfracao.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (index < filterNomeAnexo.length) {
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 20.0, 1.0),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              'ANEXOS.',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 28.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                  return ListaAnexos(filterNomeAnexo[index]);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
```

COMO ESTA TRAZENDO OS DADOS (NÃO ESTÁ RETORNANDO A LISTA E O TEXTO ESTÁ DUPLICADO)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você é o responsável por escolher o que exibir em cada caso.

Sua função:

```
(BuildContext context, int index) {}
```

Recebe apenas um `index` como parâmetro, que vai variar de 0 até o valor que você colocar em `itemCount` (exclusivamente). No seu caso vai até

```
(filterNomeInfracao.length + filterNomeAnexo.length)-1
```

Portanto você deve verificar o valor do índice antes de exibir o Widget correspondente:

```
if(index < filterNomeAnexo.length){
Return Text('Lista Anexos');
}
return Text('Lista Infrações');
```

Isso irá fazer a lista de anexos vir antes da lista de Infrações. Para fazer o contrário você pode verificar o tamanho da outra lista antes.

Outra opção, talvez mais legível fosse fazer duas `ListView.builder()`. Uma para a lista de Anexos, e outra para a de infrações:

```
body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          itemCount: filterNomeInfracao.length
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Text(filterNomeInfracao[index]);

          })),
        Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          itemCount: filterNomeAnexo.length 
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Text(filterNomeAnexo[index]);
          })),],
```

Ambos os modos irão funcionar.

Comment: Estou criando duas novas ListView.builder() como citado......como pode observar no coditgo que coloquei lá em cima, eu tentei criar um novo ListViewBuilder dentro do mesmo Expanded(   (Ou seja ta chamando duas ListView)
ele da erro no child

The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified.
Try removing one of the named arguments, or correcting one of the names to reference a different named parameter

Comment: se puder editar a resposta de cima colocando como ficaria duas lista dentro do Expanded  agradeço muito de verdade, sou iniciante estou apanhando muito.

Comment: No código que você postou só existe um ListView. De qualquer forma, editei a resposta com o exemplo como você sugeriu. Cada Listview tem seu próprio Expanded. Sugiro você pegar os Cookbooks oficiais do Flutter para estudar. Tentar fazer pulando etapas pode fazer demorar mais tempo para conseguir o que deseja.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo de vdd, porem eu coloquei dois Expanded está do jeito que vc me informou porem usando dois expanded Ele apenas joga uma lista em baixo da outra ai a lista toda não fica Scrolavel eu preciso dar o scrool em uma lista só depois scrolar a outra lista
achei meio dificil de entender eu gravei a tela para dar uma olhada:  
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MikRo_ZIk-4xTg2Ooo9OwFyowDut7Mrw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Você tentou a primeira forma? Com o ```if(index<length)```, como requisitado na pergunta?

Comment: Amigo, dei o CTRL+z aqui para voltar do jeito que fiz que vc citou if(index<length) da uma olhada na edição que fiz na publicação de como fiz e como está

Answer (score 1):

Você tem a possibilidade de unir as duas listas em uma só e trabalhar validando o tipo do dado no momento que for utilizar.

Vamos supor que você possuí essas duas classes

```
class Infracao {
  Infracao({this.id, this.descricao});
  int id;
  String descricao;
}

class Multa {
  Multa({this.id, this.gravidade});
  int id;
  String gravidade;
}
```

Então você recebe os dados das infrações e multas, daí podemos unir ambas as listas e trabalhar da seguinte maneira:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
  List<Infracao> infracoes = [
    Infracao(id: 0, descricao: "Teste 0"),
    Infracao(id: 1, descricao: "Teste 1"),
    Infracao(id: 2, descricao: "Teste 2"),
  ];
  
  List<Multa> multas = [
    Multa(id: 0, gravidade: "Alta"),
    Multa(id: 1, gravidade: "Média"),
    Multa(id: 2, gravidade: "Baixa"),
  ];  
  
  List<dynamic> dados = [];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    dados.clear();
    dados.addAll(infracoes);
    dados.addAll(multas);
    
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: dados.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
        if (dados[index] is Infracao)
          return Text("Infração: "+ (dados[index] as Infracao).descricao);
        else
          return Text("Multa: "+ (dados[index] as Multa).gravidade);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

*Obs.: Se estiver trabalhando com `StatefullWidget`, junte as listas no `initState()`*

Fazendo desta forma, você vai ter apenas umas lista e dentro dela tu trata qual o tipo do dado que vai ser desenhado utilizando a validação

```
if (dados[index] is Infracao)
  return Text("Infração: "+ (dados[index] as Infracao).descricao);
else
  return Text("Multa: "+ (dados[index] as Multa).gravidade);
```

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda, vc pode dar uma olahda na alteração que fiz na publicação onde se inicia em CONFORME CITADO NO COMENTARIO A FORMA FEITA:
ele não ta trazendo os a LISTA no return e ta duplicando os Text e usando dois Expanded ele ocorre esse problema do video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MikRo_ZIk-4xTg2Ooo9OwFyowDut7Mrw/view

Comment: Mano, não queira por a carroça na frente dos burros... Te aconselho a parar o que está fazendo e ir estudar um pouco mais sobre o framework. Você não está sabendo lidar corretamente com uma `ListView` que é um Widget muito comum em aplicações. Deixo aqui um exemplo de estudo para você [Work with long lists](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists)

Comment: Você atualizou a sua pergunta com base em uma outra resposta. No caso veja se é realmente o melhor a se fazer.... E outra, compare a minha resposta e a do @Naslausky, leia as duas, entenda, compare que você deve conseguir montar. O seu problema é o mesmo de outra pergunta sua que lhe ajudei, preste atenção que consegue.