# Flutter : ListView Builder - Texto

Tags: flutter, dart

Boa tarde, galera!

Poderiam me auxiliar em uma dúvida?

## O que estou fazendo:

- Eu criei uma **ListView.builder** dentro do meu body. Como podem observar eu estou passando um itemCount: dados.length, porque eu criei uma Lista **Dados** que ajunta todas as outras Listas
  o retorno do meu dados[index] está:

  ```
    [Infracao{id: 20, conteudo: DIRIGIR veículo SEM possuir CNH}]
    [Anexo{id: 40, nome: GESTOS DE AGENTES, conteudo: movimentos convencionais de braço, adotados exclusivamente pelos agentes de autoridades de trânsito nas vias, para orientar, indicar o direi

    [Fiscalizacao{id: 40, nome: VIADUTO,}]
  ```

### E como estou fazendo e minha Dúvida

Como podem observar preciso comparar `if (dados[index] is Infracao) return ListaInfracao(dados[index] as Infracao);` e assim para os outros ou seja ele me retorna a LISTA
Porem alem da lista eu gostaria que ele  trouxesse um Pedding chamando um **Text("Infrações")** em baixo retorna a lista e assim para os demais.

Poque da forma que está ele só ta dando um return na lista e antes de dar o return na lista eu gostaria de retornar tmb um  TEXTO, **abaixo está imagem de como está atualmente como gostaria que ficasse**.

```
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            itemCount: dados.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              if (dados[index] is Infracao) 
                //AQUI RETORNARIA UM PEDDING TEXT();
                //DEPOIS A LISTA
                return ListaInfracao(dados[index] as Infracao);
              if (dados[index] is Anexo)
                return ListaAnexos(dados[index] as Anexo);
              else 
                return ListaFiscalizacao(dados[index] as Fiscalizacao);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
```

### **COMO ESTÁ ATUALMENTE TRAZENDO A LISTA DE INFRAÇÕES E ANEXOS NO PRINT**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### COMO EU GOSTARIA QUE RETORNASSE

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Hey Victor beleza? Que tal utilizar apenas uma conta para fazer as perguntas? E tente finalizar uma pergunta antes de começar a fazer outras! É sempre bom dar um feedback para quem está tentando lhe ajudar.

Comment: vou fechar a outra é que vcs comentou de abrir outra pergunta para minha dúvida porem na minha outra conta o limite bloqueou e eu preciso tirar essa ´duvida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

é importante você saber formular a sua pergunta, para que seja fácil entender qual a sua necessidade, de qualquer maneira vejamos se isso pode te ajudar:

```
if (dados[index] is Infracao) 
   //AQUI RETORNARIA UM PEDDING TEXT();
   //DEPOIS A LISTA
   return ListaInfracao(dados[index] as Infracao);
```

Se eu bem entendi a sua pergunta, caso o `Widget` seja `Infracao` você precisa retornar um Widget `ListaInfracao` com um padding certo? Se este o caso você pode realizar isso em vários modos:

O modo mais simples seria ultilizando um [Padding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD5RtLhhubg):

Então o seu return seria:

```
return Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: ALTURA_DESEJADA),
   child: ListaInfracao(dados[index] as Infracao);
);
```

Ou você criar a sua lista dentro a um `Container`:

```
return Container(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: ALTURA_DESEJADA),
   child: ListaInfracao(dados[index] as Infracao);
);
```

Organize melhor o seu código, você está criando 3 listas diferentes entre elas, dentro a uma Lista, então praticamente você pode ter 3 ListViews dentro a 1 ListView, por que não criar diretamente as ListViews que você precisa? Se todas as ListViews são parecidas (ao menos pela imagem parece que sim), por que não criar um único widget, que recebe a sua lista generica e cria a view?

Comment: Na real ele quer fazer um lista agrupada, mas pelo visto não quer ir atrás das coisas mais básicas da linguagem... Assim como você, eu já dei um caminho a ele em uma outra pergunta dele mesmo ([Essa aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/458710/d%c3%bavida-flutter-listview)) e também já indiquei um package próprio para o que ele deseja... Falta é empenho da parte dele buscar entender antes de aplicar.